# PWM driving of high-power LED with an arduino and regulation problem

Tags: led-driver

I need to drive 2 red and 2 blue high-power LEDs for an application (LED indicated below).
[image: Bar LED]
First of all, I connected the LEDs directly to the 12V power supply and measured the currents they draw.
[image: red_not_regulated]
As you can see, the red one draws about 1.4A.
[image: blue_not_regulated]
As you can see, the blue one draws about 0.5A.
However, since the battery in my application will be 24V, I used the LM2596 voltage reducer for regulation.However, when I use a voltage regulator, the LEDs start to draw less current (I will share below).
[image: red_regulated]
As you can see the red LED draws 0.7A after regulation.
[image: blue_regulated]
As you can see the red LED draws 0.3A after regulation.
**My first question is, why did the LEDs start to draw lower current after regulation?How can I fix?**
**My second question is that I want to use MOSFET to drive these LEDs with PWM, I have shared two circuits below which should I use?Why?**
[image: 1aa]
**Circuit-1**
[image: 2aa]
**Circuit-2**

Comment: I must admit I don't understand your first question: Compare the *power* going through your device.

Comment: Please use the built-in schematic editor to draw proper schematics for your circuits rather than fritzing cartoons. Also, just type in the numbers you read; don't take photographs of your power supply.

Answer (score 1):

> I used the LM2596 voltage reducer for regulation

Well, there's your problem. Actually it isn't a problem because the LM2596 is a buck regulator so, pretty much all the power going in becomes the power going to your LEDs. So you have two scenarios for red: -

- 12 volts and 1.4 amps = 16.8 watts
- 24 volts and 0.7 amps = 16.8 watts

Problem? No problem other than understanding what an LM2596 does.

> I have shared two circuits below which should I use?Why?

No, they are not circuits so that cannot be answered reasonably.

I would also suggest you check to see that your LED strips can work with constant voltage supply without using a current limiter.

Answer (score 0):

> Driving LEDs directly with a constant voltage source

**Don't do this!** The LEDs you show are designed to be driven by a constant **current** source ...NOT a constant voltage source.
The Vf of the LEDs (several in series/parallel combination on the module) will vary with temperature and forward current so it is very challenging to drive with a constant voltage.

If you want to drive the modules from a constant voltage source you could put a series resistor in place. Since you are using a 24V battery your voltage changes over a fairly narrow range and you could do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvPT47.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Obviously the power dissipated in the resistors may be a problem but no worse than any other linear regulation method.
You could drive the cathodes of the LED modules direct from your PWM FET and get brightness and on/off control. A simple but warm solution.

You could also minimize the power dissipation by using your 2496 based switching regulator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhnZKL.png)</sup>

In the circuit above you use a switching regulator (Buck) to transform the 24V to 14V, and R1 and R2 swamp the potential Vf changes due to temperature change. Not perfect current control nut likely more than adequate for your purpose.
Note: I've ignored the efficiency of the Buck regulator in the current calculations.
You can drive the cathodes of the LED modules with your PWM FET.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but there is a point I don't understand. Why did we set the output of the regulator to 14V?My second question is, what is the place of MOSFET in the circuit you established in the final?